# Renaming a Dynamic File in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, rename

I am trying to rename a dynamic file within VBA code. The structure of this dynamic file is as below, and to what it should be renamed to

[image]

I have searched many places to look for renaming in VBA code for excel but couldn't find.

I tried File copy method and using wildcard and it errors out for the following code :

[image]

FileCopy "\C:\Users\User12345\Desktop\ReportFolder*.csv*", "C:\Users\User12345\Desktop\ReportFolder\Daily_Report.csv"

RunTime Error 52 : Bad Filename or Number

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are renaming to the same file name each file?

Comment: You can't use `*` in `FileCopy`. Try using `Dir` first maybe.

Comment: BigBen, I am new to this, can you please explain how this is done. Thank you so much.

Comment: There are many questions on SO dealing with `Dir`. Also there is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function).

Comment: Nathan_Sav - Yes , always renaming to same file. There is only 1 dynamic file inside a folder for a given day, and I need to convert that to Daily_Report.csv

Answer (score 0):

If you just have only one file in the directory so let the code detect the file name and then rename it as you wish. Try the following code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sFolder As String, sFile As String
    sFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TestFolder\"
    sFile = Dir(sFolder & "*csv")
    Do While Len(sFile) > 0
        Name sFolder & sFile As sFolder & "Daily_Report.csv"
        Exit Do
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe change the `.xlsx` to `.csv`? Also, if there's only one file to be changed in the directory, there's no need for a `Do While` loop.